# Solution of differential equation $(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 - x\frac{dy}{dx} + y = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A Solution of differential equation $(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 - x\frac{dy}{dx} + y = 0$ is

> A) $y = 0$ B) $y = 2x$ C) $y = 2x - 4$ D) $y = 2x^2 - 4$

The answer to the problem is given as $y = 2x - 4$ which makes sense since $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2$ hence the equation becomes $(4) - x(2) + (2x-4) = 0$ which is correct

However I do not understand why $y=0$ cannot be the solution to this equation since $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$ in this case and so the differential equation should be true in this case aswell. Is there something I am missing or making some wrong consideration ? or is there any possible error in the answers ?

Comment: $y=0$ is indeed a solution.

Comment: Was it said that only one choice is possible ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust it was given in single correct which only one option given, should probably have been in multicorrect then. Probably some error on their side then.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Clairaut equation
$$
y=xy'-y'^2
$$
which has linear solutions
$$
y=Cx-C^2
$$
and a singular solution/envelope
$$
y=\frac{x^2}4.
$$